# Updating Android preferences from http rest service call

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

How could one dynamically updated SharedPreferences or Default Preferences from a restful web service. I would ideally like to be able to push changes to the phone, but it is Android 2.1+ So I think push is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would construct a service which sits resident, in the background and polls  your webservice at a set interval.  Setting up push notification is possible, but I think you'll find it easier to do it with a service and it doesn't require any outside facilities (like push notification would).

Construct an Android service and, in that service, have it setup a handler or timer event which goes off at a set interval.  At this time, do an HTTP request for your remote webservice, read the result and then push the values into the SharedPreferences.

[Service info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

[Timer info](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)

If you want this to run even if your code is not currently running, take a look at [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)